# TCP/IP Socket programming in Python: how to make server close the connection after 10 seconds

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, asyncore

I need to write a simple program (no thread allowed) using Python for a
simple request/response stateless server. client
sends a request and  server responds with a response. Also it needs to handle multiple transaction
This is the simple one I am using:

```
import asyncore, socket

class Server(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.bind(('', port))
        self.listen(1)

    def handle_accept(self):
        # when we get a client connection start a dispatcher for that
        # client
        socket, address = self.accept()
        print 'June, Connection by', address
        EchoHandler(socket)

class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    # dispatcher_with_send extends the basic dispatcher to have an output
    # buffer that it writes whenever there's content
    def handle_read(self):
        self.out_buffer = self.recv(1024)
        if not self.out_buffer:
            self.close()

s = Server('', 5088)

syncore.loop(timeout=1, count=10)


import asyncore, socket

class Client(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    def __init__(self, host, port, message):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect((host, port))
        self.out_buffer = message

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()

    def handle_read(self):
        print 'June Received', self.recv(1024)
        self.close()

c = Client('', 5088, 'Hello, world')
asyncore.loop(1)
```

Comment: There's a timeout parameter to `asyncore.loop()`, it seems like this would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Pythons native socket library supports timeouts out of the box:

socket.settimeout(value)

So something like this should work:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 12345))
sock.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
conn.settimeout(10)
```

A bit more high level: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html and https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example